# Glute exercises for someone with degenerative disk disease

Tags: squats, deadlifts, glutes

I have degenerative disk disease in my low back. I've been weight training for over 30 years and I've had degenerative disk disease for about 10 years. I've adjusted my training over the years as it has gotten progressively worse. For example, I no longer do weighted squats or do deadlifts. Most recently, I stopped doing heavy hip thrusts.

I want to keep my glutes strong because I also have problems with my knees tracking and strengthening my glutes has really helped with this issue. I know glutes are made up of fast twitch and slow twitch fibers which respond to both heavy and light training. Can anyone suggest an exercise I can do with heavy weight for my glutes that does not result in compression of my lower back or heavy weight on my lower back (e.g. hip thrusts)?

Comment: How much were you pulling before? Hard to imagine that someone who pulled a lot on deadlift reaches a point where they can't pull at all

Comment: I can still lift heavy on deadlifts and hip thrusts, but have back pain for several days afterwards. I'm concerned I'm accelerating the degenerative disk disease.

Comment: How heavy are we talking ehre? @JT_here405?

Comment: Well, I never said I couldn't pull at all. Just that it caused a lot of pain due to the degenerative disk disease. I'm making a choice not to be in pain, and seeking alternative exercises.

Comment: What about the guidelines that suggest avoiding "making statements based on opinion" @trystwithfreedom ??   This is my first time posting in the group. It has a chilling effect to be faced with an opinion.                                                                        "But avoid …

    Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
    Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience."

Comment: I understand, but I am asking, what is the weight that you were pulling before? 100kg? 200kg? 300kg? I am trying to get a picture of how heavy these numbers are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Belt Squat:

[image]

These can be hard to set up, but they're very helpful for this kind of thing. I've done them with lower-back injuries and was able to perform them pretty well with a surprising amount of load.

Basically you attach a belt around your hips and lower in to a squat. Some gyms have these machines, but if not you can use a landmine attachment like in the image above. You can add a handle in front of you to hold on to and let you lean further back which allows for a greater stretch in the glutes.

2. Reverse Hyperextention:

[image]

Also good for lower-back development without loading too much on the spine itself. The idea here is to lay on a table or bench and lift your legs up. Some gyms have machines for this as well which have a weight attachment. If you lack the attachment, then you can lift a dumbbell with your feet or hang weight on your legs.

3. Cable glute kickbacks

[image]

A staple for any women's bodybuilding program, but that's because it's really effective. In my opinion, men should grow up and do it as well.

Performed either straight back for glute max development or at a 45 degree angle for more glute medius development.  You can stand on a plate to lift your foot off the floor so you can get a full range of motion.

4. Any glute machine.

Pretty much any machine that specifically targets the glutes will have low-impact on the spine.

---

Of course, like any exercise, ease in to them to make sure you can perform them safely.

Comment: Thank you so much! The belt squat is especially what I'm looking for.

Comment: Just a minor point: I'd be hesitant to call anything with straight leg extension "glute exercise" since insufficient glutes are compensated by the hamstrings there. That does not happen with a bent knee/short lever.

Comment: Noted. Thank you for pointing this out.